# MySQL left join with where condition

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables like this

**rooms**

```
id | number
1  | 111
2  | 112
```

**occupied_rooms**

```
id | check_in   | check_out  | room_id
1  | 2017-10-01 | 2017-10-04 | 1
```

I want to get all the unoccupied rooms according to date check_in and check_out for this I tried

```
select r.id
     , r.number
  from rooms r
  left join occupied_rooms o
    on r.id = o.room_id
 where (o.check_in not between "2017-10-05" and "2017-10-08" )
 or (o.check_in >= "2017-10-05" and o.check_out <= "2017-10-08"))
```

but this query giving me result like this. which is incorrect.

```
id  | number
1   | 111
```

What is wrong with this query?
Thank you for your any help and suggestions

Comment: What is the default value of check_in , check_out ? is that null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the two tables on the condition that the `id` matches and the range of intended stay overlaps with the range in the `occupied_rooms` table.

```
SELECT r.*
FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN occupied_rooms t
    ON r.id = t.id AND
       ('2017-10-02' <= t.check_out AND '2017-10-03' >= t.check_in)
WHERE
    t.id IS NULL;   -- NULL value indicates the room did not overlap
                    -- with any existing reservations
```

You can also check out this [great reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) on how to deal with overlapping ranges in SQL queries.  It makes the problem you are facing much simpler.

## Demo

Comment: thanks I added "is null" and it worked as expected when query is fired from php script but it still giving two result when query is run in phpmyadmin it supposed to give only one result  -> 
select rooms.number
 from `rooms` left join `occupied_rooms` on `rooms`.`id` = `occupied_rooms`.`room_id` 
 where (`occupied_rooms`.`check_in` not between "2017-10-02" and "2017-10-08" or (`occupied_rooms`.`check_in` >= "2017-10-02" and `occupied_rooms`.`check_out` <= "2017-10-08")) or `occupied_rooms`.`id` is null

Comment: Edit my demo, update it and paste the link here.  I am guessing your data is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your data in table **occupied_rooms** meets the first condition in "where";

**check_in** date(2017-10-01) is not between "2017-10-05" and "2017-10-08" and your **where** is **or**.

Thus, the result is included this data.

Can you tell us what output you expect?

Comment: Overlapping ranges are a bit much complex than this, q.v. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap